# Как можно отключить редирект в NGINX на HTTPS только для конкретной страницы сайта?

Tags: linux, nginx, битрикс, https

Как можно отключить редирект в NGINX на HTTPS только для конкретной страницы сайта? /local/1c/exchange_s1_orders.php

Comment: Это бессмысленно и небезопасно. Если вы сделаете техническую возможность отключения https даже для одной страницы — этим обязательно воспользуется MITM-злоумышленник, отключив https для всего сайта целиком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял это для обмена с учетной программой. По-моему лучший способ будет создать отдельный виртуальный сервер для этой страницы на отдельном порту и с аксес листом.

```
server {
        listen 2480;
        listen [::]:2480;

        server_name _;

        allow  192.168.1.0/24;
        deny   all;

....
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный вариант! Попробую! Да это для обмена заказами 1С-Bitrix с УТ 1С

Comment: Ут11 нормально ходит по хттпс

Comment: если есть редирект на HTTPS то не работает... Вот цитата ТП БУС : 1С не поддерживает редиректы.
Если сайт работает по https, то и адрес в настройках модуля должен быть указан с https.
Какой модуль и конфигурацию вы используете?

С уважением,
Ведущий специалист отдела технической поддержки
Емельяненко Игорь

Comment: если в ут сразу написать https - работает. нет редиректа - нет проблемы